# SQL: Getting a value multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a problem getting the same value multiple times and I don't know what I am doing wrong, it's probably something very simple but nothing seems to work for me, and as I said, I need it for a school project and I have only been doing this for about a week.

This is my code:

```
select hobby
from preshobby
order by hobby asc
```

When I click execute I get the same value a couple of times. For example:

```
Wrestling
Wlking
Walking
Walking
Walking
Walking
Touch Football
Tennis
```

I need the result to be in ascending order and each value should only appear once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct`:

```
select distinct hobby
from preshobby
order by hobby
```

Note that you don't need to specify `asc` with `order by` as ascending is the default sort order in most versions of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In your table you have probably many entries with repeated hobbies. So you need to group them like this

```
select hobby
from preshobby
group by hobby order by hobby asc
```

Answer (score -1):

You are basically selecting all the values of hobbies you have entered in the database column.. Since there are many people with same hobby.. when you query the table for the column, you see repetitive values. Use distinct like this..

```
select distinct hobby from table Name;
```

And default order is asc so you need not specify any value unless you need it descending.